# Expo GooglePlacesAutocomplete currentLocation not working on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, google-places-autocomplete, currentlocation

In Expo I'm using GooglePlacesAutocomplete, and I'm trying to add the current location label. It's interesting because in Android it works with the react-native-geolocation-service, but in iOS it doesn't. Here's my code:

```
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from "react-native-google-places-autocomplete";
navigator.geolocation = require("react-native-geolocation-service");
const chooseOrigin = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
        placeholder="Choose origin"
        fetchDetails={true}
        autoFocus={true}
        currentLocation={true}
        currentLocationLabel="My location"
        textInputProps={{
          placeholderTextColor: "#ccc",
          autoFocus: true,
        }}
        onPress={(data, details = null) => {
            console.log(data, details);
          }}
   />
export default chooseOrigin;
```

Adding this line:

```
navigator.geolocation = require("react-native-geolocation-service");
```

Throws this error but only on iOS Simulator:

```
[iOS Simulator Error][1]
```

Tried with "@react-native-community/geolocation" like documentation says but got error on both, Android and iOS Simulator.
Changed line to:

```
navigator.geolocation = require('@react-native-community/geolocation');
```

and got this error:
[Error in iOS and Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LORwt.png)

Don't understand yet if i'm missing something or the documentation isn't updated. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

navigator.geolocation = require("expo-location") worked for me.

navigator.geolocation = require("react-native-geolocation-service") OR
navigator.geolocation = require('@react-native-community/geolocation')

need pods configurations for IOS .

Comment: This fixed the error but now I'm getting this instead: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentPosition' of undefined".